# with his mouth wide open

Tags: single-word-requests

What other words can I use to replace the following:

> "with his mouth wide open"

I'm trying to describe a person who was shocked by bad news. I need to show, not tell. I have used *"with his mouth wide open"* twice and want to find another way to describe a person who is shocked. Any suggestions?

Comment: "He was shocked."

Comment: Maybe 'wide-mouthed' or 'His jaws wide apart' or 'The gap in between jaw and head further increasing'.

Comment: 'Gaping' describes the mouth position, or if you have already mentioned the mouth twice you could go on to say that he was pale and trembling, for example.

Comment: Aghast, agog, agape.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the idiom [**someone's jaw dropped**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/someone-s-jaw-dropped):

> His jaw dropped in surprise when he heard the news.

Answer (score 0):

What would a shocked person look and sound like?

For example, you could try writing something like this, *'His eyes were wide open with fear and disbelief'*.